# Since v9: nz-table > ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on ant-table-cell-fix-left-last

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I have a pretty complex nz-table with fix columns left and right, on v8.5 it worked, but since the update to v9.1 I get:

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'ant-table-cell-fix-left-last': 'false'. Current value: 'true'.`

I have to remove all nzLeft and nzRight values to have a clear console again. I do not change these values and tried to render the table seconds after the page was rendered: same error.
So it seems, it's an "internal" problem of the library.

I wasn't able to reproduce it with a CodeSandbox example. I'm thankful for every hint.

EDIT:
Was able to reproduce it: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-elbakyan-b3ylx?file=/src/app/app.component.tsIt happens when a nzRight (not the last) or nzLeft (not the first) has a *ngIf on it, even if the value doesn't changes.

**I opened a issue for this bug: https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/5206**